# Expectation and Variance using generating function with dependent variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions, variance, expected-value

> Suppose $X\sim\operatorname{Po}(\lambda)$ and  $Y\sim\operatorname{Po}(\mu)$. Given $Z=X+Y$ , find the $\mathbb{E}[Z]$ and $\operatorname{Var}[Z]$ by first finding the generating function of $Z$.

I've already found the generating function of $Z$ to be $\exp(\lambda(t\exp(\mu(t-1))-1)$.

I'm just really lost in how to find the expectation and variance. I'm not sure if I should differentiate them. Any advice or guided steps would be great!

Edit (28/10/18) : I already got the answer with the help of Clement C and doing some more digging. $\mathbb{E}[Z]$ = $(\lambda)(1-\mu)$ and $\operatorname{Var}[Z]$= $\lambda(1+3\mu+\mu^2)$ . Thank you! (answers I have are correct with double checking across google. just needed to know the middle steps)

Comment: You probably forgot to mention that $X$ and $Y$ are independently distributed.

Comment: How did you find this MGF? Assume $X,Y$ to be independent (if they aren't, which relation do they have?) you have $$\mathbb{E}e^{t Z} = \mathbb{E}[e^{t X}e^{t Y}]= \mathbb{E}[e^{t X}]\mathbb{E}[e^{t Y}] = e^{(\lambda+\mu)(e^t-1)}$$

Comment: (and even if $X,Y$ are dependent, the expectation for $Z=X+Y$ should still end up being $\lambda+\mu$ by linearity, which your expression for the MGF of $Z$ does not give.)

Comment: this question is a branching process question to which I summarised. Basically, X are the mothers and Y are the daughters (where Yi are the number of daugthers of mother i).

Comment: @sallyg Then are you certain to have correctly written how $Z$ is defined (as $X+Y$)? If $Z=X+Y$, then $\mathbb{E}[Z]=\mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[Y]$ regardless of dependencies...

Comment: But anyways, once you have the MGF you can get expectation and varince using my answer, all it takes is some differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if the MGF is sufficiently differentiable at $0$,
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \mathbb{E}[e^{tZ}]\Big|_0
= \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{d}{dt} e^{tZ} \Big|_0 \right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[ Z e^{tZ} \Big|_0 \right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[ Z e^{0} \right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[ Z \right]
$$
while 
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \mathbb{E}[e^{tZ}]\Big|_0
= \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} e^{tZ} \Big|_0 \right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[ Z^2 e^{tZ} \Big|_0 \right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[ Z^2 \right]
$$
so that computing the first and second derivatives of the MGF you found at $0$ will give you the first and second moments of the r.v., and from there you have the expectation (first moment) and can easily obtain the variance.

*(Switching differentiation and expectation requires justification, but I am assuming you can take it from granted from your class or textbook.)*